# Why isn't the emissive power of a black body 1?

Tags: thermal-radiation

My text book has a question which says that the emissive power of a black body isn't one but the answer states that the absorptive power is 1, considering that $$e=a \tag{Kirchoff's law}$$

and a black body is defined as an object which has $$e=1$$ Then why isn't $a=1$

> 5. Choose correct options
>
> (a)  Good absorbers of a particular wavelength are good emitters of same wavelength.This statement was given by Kirchoff.
>
> (b) At low temperature of a body the rate of cooling is directly proportional to temperature of the body.This statement was given by Newton.
>
> (c) Emissive power of a perfectly black body is 1
>
> (d) Absorptive power of a perfectly black body is 1

The answer is given as (a,d)

---

**Waves and Thermodyanamics** by *DC Pandey* 15th edition

Comment: Can you quote the textbook question for context and accuracy?

Comment: @J.Murray Done..

Answer (score 1):

For blackbody $a=e=1. a=1$ implies that the blackbody absorbs all radiation falling on it. For anything that is not a blackbody, $0≤e=a<1$

Answer (score 1):

The *emissivity* ($e$) of a perfectly black body is 1. Emissivity is the ratio of energy emitted by a body to the energy emitted by a black body. The *emissive power* is the energy emitted per unit area per unit time. The emissive power of a black body is not 1, and it varies with temperature.

It is true that emissivity = absorptive power = 1 for a black body, i.e., $e=a=1$